# How to add default values to input arguments in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have this input type and I would like to add a default Value to one of the fields. I want to add 0 to the value field inside the ExampleInput.

```
type ExampleType {
  value: Int
  another: String
}

type Mutation {
  example(input: ExampleInput): ExampleType
}

input ExampleInput {
  value: Int
  another: String
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It looks like the [grammar](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Input-Objects) [allows](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#InputValueDefinition) [default values](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#DefaultValue) on input object types, so you can declare

```graphql
input ExampleInput {
  value: Int = 0
  another: String
  isAvailable: Boolean = false
}
```

[The spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Input-Objects) is clear that default values exist and explains how they get used (first bullet under "Input Coercion").

(Whether any specific tooling supports this is probably variable: graphql.org had an informal version of the IDL for quite a while before it was actually in the spec, and I have the impression some libraries haven't caught up to the released spec yet.)

Comment: how to set default values in manual types declaration ? like 
new GraphQLObjectType({
     args:{
          isAdmin:{type:GraphQLBoolean}
     }
})
how to set isAdmin to False by default?

Answer (score 1):

In a programmatic/object-based (or code-first) approach, you can set a default value like this for the InputObjectType:

```js
 const exampleInput = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
   name: "ExampleInput",
   fields: () => ({
     value: { type: graphql.GraphQLInt, defaultValue: 0 },
     another: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(graphql.GraphQLString) },
     isAvailable: { type: graphql.GraphQLBoolean, defaultValue: false },
   }),
 });
```

by using `defaultValue` keyword.